# Can I use lands from previous sets?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

bit of a  Magic n00b here. I was wondering, can I use basic lands that are not currently in standard? (eg dragon's maze) I just thought this might be  thing as no matter what set ut's in, basic lands do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that matters for card legality is the name. Whether it's a "Forest" or "Grizzly Bears", the set that it was printed in is irrelevant; all that matters is if "Forest" is legal in the current format.

Comment: With the usual restrictions on card legality. (Black or white border, rounded corners, not marked, etc) You can even use the lands from the Unhinged.